# Sending image to server using socket programming in flutter

Tags: python, flutter, sockets, http, flutter-http

I have a server-side program in python that is expecting an image and is working fine when tested with a client-side program in python.

I want to send image to this server using flutter and I'm failing to do so..

Here's my server-side code

```
import socket       #server


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # AF_INET = IP, SOCK_STREAM = TCP
server.bind(('localhost', 1112))  # 127.0.0.1
server.listen()

client_socket, client_address = server.accept()

file = open('2.jpg', "wb")
image_chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)  # stream-based protocol

while image_chunk:
    file.write(image_chunk)
    image_chunk = client_socket.recv(1024)

file.close()
client_socket.close()
```

I have tried using `dio`, `http` and `MultiPart`

Here are snippets from my failed attempts:

1. `MultiPart`

   ```
    var uri = Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:1112');
    var request = MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
      ..files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'picture', filePath,
          contentType: MediaType('application', 'jpeg')));
    var response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
   ```
2. `Dio`

   ```
   Dio dio = new Dio();
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromPath(filePath, filename: basename(filePath),
        contentType: MediaType('application', 'jpeg'),)
    });
   await dio.post('https://10.0.2.2:1112', data: formData);
   ```

**I'm able to create a connection but I'm not able to send the file.**

**P.S: I have almost no experience of working with sockets, so I'm stuck at this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to connect to a socket api (not websocket these are different) via HTTP request and on server-side expecting to get image bytes but that's not gonna happen because as you know HTTP has it's own specification [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). so what you will get there is some http headers and body.

Actually you can send http request to a socket but on the server-side you must do the heavy lifting. i mean reading http header line by line and then reading the `Transfer-Encoding` and `Content-Length` headers to know how to read the remaining bytes of the request, and then parsing the body data.

> The Content-Length entity header indicates the size of the entity-body, in bytes, sent to the recipient.

> The Transfer-Encoding header specifies the form of encoding used to safely transfer the payload body to the user.

The solution is either:

1. using dart socket library at the client side and then sending your image through socket instead of http request (this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-sockets-in-dart-15b443007bc9) might be helpful )
2. Or creating a [RESTFUL API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and send your image via http request like you did before.

hope i could help you:)

Comment: Thanks, You answer helped me a lot, but I'm stuck on this issue, see if you can help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532975/how-to-send-image-over-socket-connection

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with websocket, you have to checkout this package [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel).

You first need to make connection with your socket channel using

```
var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://localhost:1234'));
```

To listen to changes from your websocket channel, you will use:

```
 channel.stream.listen((message) {
    print("NEW MESSAGE");
  });
```

To send data to your websocket channel, you will use:

```
channel.sink.add("your data");
```

Finally, do not forget to close your websocket channel stream using:

```
channel.sink.close();
```

Comment: I tried it to upload an image but the image I receive at server-side is empty.
Can you emphasise on how to send an image?